# difference between MVC and spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, difference

i started learning springs recently. i came to know about both mvc and springs frameworks!
the thing is what is the difference between MVC and spring MVC?
i need the exact difference between them. i'm a bit confused!
please help me.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is a design pattern. Spring MVC is an implementation of MVC.

Comment: thanks for reply kevin.
generally we use IOC module in java applications. MVC framework must follow some rules(i.e app should have model- view - controller).
i couldn't figure out how spring mvc is implemented from mvc??

Comment: @bharat It's very simple. Spring MVC uses Models (M) / services, Views (V) and Controllers (C) to get from request to response.

Comment: got it bart!
i have checked the sample spring mvc app.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a difference, like @wxkevin said, MVC (Model, View, Controller) is a design pattern. Spring is just a framework, just like ASP.NET or even PHP. these all can use the MVC design principals.